# Regular expression alternative for escape character

Tags: regex

I want to apply a regex in an SQL query for "a number of non-pipe chars followed by either pipe or end-of-line.
So I use `'([^|]*)(\||$)'` for this.
Unluckily I am using a tool for running the query and that tool removes backslashes from the text I feed it - so the regex fails.\

Is there an alternative regex for this that does not use \ ?
Would, for example, `'([^|]*)($||)'` work?
Or does that also require a backslash, as in `'([^|]*)($|\|)'`?

Comment: You could use a character class `[|]` in the same way as you use a negated one at the beginning of the regex

Comment: you mean to say use '[^|]*([|]|$)' ?

Comment: Did you wrap the regex in foeward slashes? `/Regexp/`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Are you sure it removes all backslashes? It tries to prevent misuse. You may have to escape the backslash with another: \\ - Does that work?